# PHP on-line deployment

Tags: php, svn, deployment

I am looking for **online tool** for "one-click" PHP deployment from SVN repository.

In this tool I would insert SVN repository path, username and password and SSH or FTP access to my server.

Comment: On what platforms? Where is the SVN repo running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) should do the job, although it is rather more complex then just putting in paths and server credentials.